# Laravel public CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using this code to include my public style sheets:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/c_bootstrap.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style_x.css') }}"  />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/sb-admin.css') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- navbar -->
        @include ('layout.navbar')

        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
             @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the view page source:
[image]

when i click on it i get this:
[image]

so it really looks like it works. However, it's just the error CSS from Laravel error page:
[image]

**so what's the mistake I'm doing here?**

my folder:

```
|- public
|-|--- assets
|-|---|--- css
|-|---|---|--- c_bootstrap.css
|-|---|---|--- s.css
|-|---|---|--- sb-admin.css
```

Comment: yours `assets` folder spelling is wrong.

Comment: its just here in the post, edited @bonish koirala

Comment: have you tried this `asset('assets/css/c_bootstrap.css')` something like that for other files too?

Comment: doesnt work, the router doesnt allow to access files becasue its somehow trying to parse the url. im very new to laravel, im trying to put css directly to public not compile it.

Comment: Can you view your `c_bootstrap.css` page as html?

Comment: no, it works with (domain.com/public/assets/css/file.css) .. so i think its htacess problem. yes i can do it in the code with public but i want to fix it by configuring the htacess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in .htaccess file

**original:**

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**and after i edit it:**

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

**my blade layout include must have assets:**

```
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/c_bootstrap.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/style_x.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/sb-admin.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Extra for asset function:**

most of document online using asset function without including 'assets' in the path, I'm beginner in Laravel but i assume it calls the asset function in Routing:
[Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L202](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L202)
in which i cant see where it append 'assets' in the url, so maybe they changed the function? i dont know

Comment: If this was your solution, then it indicates the DocumentRoot is misconfigured for Apache. The document root for a Laravel project should be the `public/` folder, otherwise you may be unintentionally exposing sensitive configuration files, logs, uploads, etc. to the internet.

Comment: its not in public because it was in some folder because the project was in subdomain .. the apache config files in /etc was right, but .htaccess misconfigured..

Answer (score 5):

Try this for your css

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/c_bootstrap.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style_x.css') }}"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/sb-admin.css') }}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Place your assets in public directory and use the following to integrate css in laravel:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/somestylesheet.css') }}" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/style.css') }}">
```